# Error occurring while evaluation of expression in prolog

Tags: prolog, runtime-error, expression, graph-theory, instantiation-error

I am very new to Prolog. I need to find all the paths from *Source* to *Destination* in a maze.

I wrote the following clause so that I do not have to write all the edge relations explicitly:

```
neighbour(X,Y) :-
   (  X =:= Y+1
   ;  Y =:= X+1
   ;  X =:= Y+6
   ;  Y =:= X+6
   ).
```

Next, for finding path I do the following:

```
path(Source,Source,_).
path(Source,Destination,PathList) :-
    neighbour(Source,Z),                % find a neighbour of Source
    not(member(Z,PathList)),            % that is not already in the list
    % and see if there is a path from Z to Destination
    path(Z,Destination,[Source|PathList]).
```

While running it I queried the following:

```
?- path(1,2,[]).    % "Is there a path from 1 to 2?"
```

This gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [10] 1=:=_26424+1
ERROR:    [9] neighbour(1,_26452) at /Users/sujitkumar/Desktop/this sem/PL/2.pl:3
ERROR:    [8] path(1,2,[]) at /Users/sujitkumar/Desktop/this sem/PL/2.pl:30
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

I do not understand why the expression is not getting evaluated.

Comment: The operator `=:=/2` requires that each argument be totally evaluable to a number. That is, all variables must be instantiated. You cannot, for example, query `X =:= 2` and Prolog result in `X = 2`. If you want to get that kind of behavior, you need to consider using the CLP(FD) library and do `X #= Y + 1`, etc.

Comment: Actually, I finally did the same and it worked. But I don't understand what is the difference.

Comment: @SoumikMukhopadhyay, take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46756842/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-swi-prolog

Comment: The CLP(FD) operators such as `#=/2` are relational and designed for "reasoning about integers". The `=:=/2` operator is specifically designed as an imperative arithmetic operator that compares specific, real computed values. They're just designed that way.